# What do the numbers below the clock in WP 8.1 notification center mean?

Tags: 8.1, action-center

I just want to know what those numbers below the clock means in Windows Phone 8.1.

When I open the notification center, below the clock, next to the battery percentage, it says "5/6". Maybe it varies across different phones.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the current date. The exact format depends on your regional settings.

Looks like you're using US regional settings (month/day, no leading zeroes), as today is the 6th of May. On my phone it says "06/05" (UK settings, day/month).

Comment: thank you @indrek, never thought of that, my bad. anyways, thanks again. cheers! :)

Comment: accepted now. :)